# Encountering ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): issue while converting XML to DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I'm trying to read a .xml file and convert it to a Data frame using Python. The file content is as follows,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset> 
    <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = 1>
        <FIRST_NAME>Fiona</FIRST_NAME>
        <MIDDLE_NAME/>
        <LAST_NAME>Macdonald</LAST_NAME>
    </AUTHOR>
    <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = 2>
        <FIRST_NAME>Gian</FIRST_NAME>
        <MIDDLE_NAME>Paolo</MIDDLE_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Faleschini</LAST_NAME>
    </AUTHOR>
</dataset>
```

I'm encountering the below issue : **ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 22**

But when I replace the AUTHOR_UID value within quotes, I'm able to get the output as a Data frame.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset> 
    <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = "1">
        <FIRST_NAME>Fiona</FIRST_NAME>
        <MIDDLE_NAME/>
        <LAST_NAME>Macdonald</LAST_NAME>
    </AUTHOR>
    <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = "2">
        <FIRST_NAME>Gian</FIRST_NAME>
        <MIDDLE_NAME>Paolo</MIDDLE_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Faleschini</LAST_NAME>
    </AUTHOR> 
</dataset>
```

Could someone help me in understanding what is causing this issue here or a work around. As an initial step to achieve this I'm using the below code which I got from Stack Overflow.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

def parse_XML(xml_file, df_cols): 
    """Parse the input XML file and store the result in a pandas 
    DataFrame with the given columns. 
    
    The first element of df_cols is supposed to be the identifier 
    variable, which is an attribute of each node element in the 
    XML data; other features will be parsed from the text content 
    of each sub-element. 
    """
    
    xtree = et.parse(xml_file)
    xroot = xtree.getroot()
    rows = []
    
    for node in xroot: 
        res = []
        res.append(node.attrib.get(df_cols[0]))
        for el in df_cols[1:]: 
            if node is not None and node.find(el) is not None:
                res.append(node.find(el).text)
            else: 
                res.append(None)
        rows.append({df_cols[i]: res[i] 
                     for i, _ in enumerate(df_cols)})
    
    out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)
        
    return out_df
```

Our end goal is to convert any nested xml to data frame without any hard codings. Any leads on how that can be achieved will be helpful.

Comment: xml attributes are string. therefore they need to be quoted. `1` --> `"1"`